# How can I instantiate a Java generic with JNI?

Tags: java, generics, java-native-interface

If I want to instantiate a `Date`, I can use:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/Date");
jmethodID ctr = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "()V");
jobject obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, ctr);
```

But how do I instantiate an `ArrayList<String>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the same way. On VM level, there are no generics.

Comment: This isn't very helpful for how to actually do it, because you can! It's just that the generics are erased.
`env->GetMethodID(env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList"), "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");`

Answer (score 7):

@noise is correct. Generics are used simply to ensure type safety. When compiled, the compiler does "type erasure". Check out this more detailed explanation of type erasure: [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)